# How to process many gray images(over 1 channel) by cv2?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, opencv

My question is same as the title.I have a tensor and the shape is [8,64,60,80] which represent [batch,channel,height,width] respectively.I would like to process each channel and i have written 2 loops to do it.However the running speed is too slow because of the 2 loops.So I want to know can i process each channel directly by cv2?

Comment: What do you mean by process ? Can you share some code ?